What does this board do?


I can only identify a switch and terminals (sorry I am new to this stuff).

Do you have a photo of the other side?

Uhh I don’t have it with me right now, so I only have this pic. I’ll get another of the back ASAP.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

it's a paper weight

It looks like you've uploaded a second photo of the backside of a completely different board with no additional explanatory text. Please provide more context on both of these photos.

"What does this do?" = usage question

T for transmitter.  R for receiver.

I would say the question is answerable now -- added to reopen queue -- however, it will also be reverted to the earlier version (which several people have answered already, and which these edits have invalidated as they are no longer answering what was originally written :( ), and subsequently closed again for lack of information. Since you have top and bottom photographs of a new circuit board, feel free to ask a new question on that topic; please use edits in this question to improve the original question.

@pion, I see soldermask over FR2 on the circuit side and bare FR2 on the other side

This is just a guess, but it looks like a board from some RF controlled ornament or toy - or a wireless doorbell of some sorts.
There seems to be an antenna wire that gets tuned with a variable inductor.
There is a DC inlet and some power/mode setting switch.
There seems to be connectors for speaker (SPK), two motors (M1, M2) and something that may read as LED and one unlabeled connector for unknown purpose.

I found this post about a RC car kit. It uses a similar IC with a "TXM" marking like in OPs new picture.

At first glance it might be a basic audio input selector with a prefilter. I see:

Five 2-pin connectors, whose labels include M1, M2, SPK, and
presumably LIN. These suggestively could correspond to "microphone 1/2", "speaker", and "line-level audio".
Red and black cables going to each connector, a classic audio cabling color scheme
A small variable inductor. Its exact purpose is unknown but a couple of possibilities are either signal filtering (high/low/band-pass) or, less likely, impedance matching.
A multiposition switch, probably to allow selecting between audio sources
What looks to be a DC power input barrel jack, whose purpose I can't yet tell unless there are active electronics on the flip side of this board.


that does not look like a trimmer pot ... it looks like an adjustable inductor

@jsotola you are totally correct! Thanks for spotting it!

I would think it's a tunable helical filter for bandpass to the RF item.

@Lundin yeah an RF device makes sense for that size inductor, with the white cable maybe acting as an antenna
